# Print the last number within the column before keyword

Tags: bash, variables, awk

I am working with a text file in the following multi-column format

```
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1      24.950   5.224  -5.601  1.00 30.01           N  
ATOM      2  CA  MET A   1      24.822   3.740  -5.655  1.00 30.25           C  
ATOM      3  C   MET A   1      23.719   3.091  -4.771  1.00 28.98           C  
ATOM      4  O   MET A   1      23.417   1.937  -4.989  1.00 28.27           O  
ATOM      5  CB  MET A   1      26.187   3.043  -5.448  1.00 31.03           C  
ATOM      6  CG  MET A   1      26.869   3.182  -4.084  1.00 32.21           C  
ATOM      7  SD  MET A   1      28.713   3.095  -4.227  1.00 34.63           S  
ATOM      8  CE  MET A   1      29.205   3.597  -2.564  1.00 33.32           C  
ATOM      9  N   LYS A   2      23.111   3.804  -3.818  1.00 27.78           N  
ATOM     10  CA  LYS A   2      21.869   3.310  -3.188  1.00 27.21           C  
ATOM     11  C   LYS A   2      20.671   4.237  -3.440  1.00 26.27           C  
ATOM     12  O   LYS A   2      20.787   5.445  -3.300  1.00 25.96           O  
ATOM     13  CB  LYS A   2      22.027   3.091  -1.684  1.00 27.32           C  
ATOM     14  CG  LYS A   2      20.820   2.362  -1.065  1.00 27.75           C  
ATOM     15  CD  LYS A   2      20.953   2.147   0.439  1.00 28.18           C  
ATOM     16  CE  LYS A   2      19.928   1.130   0.938  1.00 29.30           C  
ATOM     17  NZ  LYS A   2      20.083   0.809   2.386  1.00 30.36           N1+
ATOM     18  N   PHE A   3      19.528   3.658  -3.808  1.00 24.92           N  
ATOM     19  CA  PHE A   3      18.306   4.421  -4.054  1.00 24.39           C  
ATOM     20  C   PHE A   3      17.161   3.823  -3.246  1.00 24.12           C  
ATOM     21  O   PHE A   3      16.991   2.597  -3.202  1.00 23.77           O  
ATOM     22  CB  PHE A   3      17.940   4.222  -5.535  1.00 23.83           C  
ATOM     23  CG  PHE A   3      19.003   4.968  -6.434  1.00 23.81           C  
ATOM     24  CD1 PHE A   3      19.132   6.337  -6.585  1.00 23.27           C  
ATOM     25  CD2 PHE A   3      19.876   4.135  -7.129  1.00 23.46           C  
ATOM     26  CE1 PHE A   3      20.110   6.868  -7.412  1.00 23.22           C  
ATOM     27  CE2 PHE A   3      20.862   4.660  -7.952  1.00 23.19           C  
ATOM     28  CZ  PHE A   3      20.975   6.027  -8.102  1.00 23.07           C   
TER
ATOM   1755  C1  4XB B 224      -2.316 -11.723  -8.228  1.00 13.30           C  
ATOM   1756  C2  4XB B 224      -3.173 -10.657  -8.950  1.00 14.61           C  
ATOM   1757  O2  4XB B 224      -4.557 -11.027  -8.952  1.00 16.65           O  
ATOM   1758  C3  4XB B 224      -2.726 -10.237 -10.411  1.00 14.12           C  
ATOM   1759  O3  4XB B 224      -3.502  -9.178 -10.953  1.00 16.48           O  
ATOM   1760  C4  4XB B 224      -1.249  -9.979 -10.435  1.00 10.48           C  
ATOM   1761  O4  4XB B 224      -0.865  -9.856 -11.797  1.00  8.86           O  
ATOM   1762  C5  4XB B 224      -0.606 -11.154  -9.841  1.00 11.33           C  
ATOM   1763  O5  4XB B 224      -0.960 -11.228  -8.458  1.00 11.66           O
```

I need to print number of the last residue (defined as a number in the 6th column) occured just before TER (in the first column).

**In that example expected output should be 3 (the last number of 6th column before TER on the next string).**

i have tried to count number of residues using the following AWK counter, which however counts the number of all the resiues (so the aim to stop it while reaching TERM in the first column)

```
 awk '{ a[$4 $6 FILENAME]++ }
   END {
     for (i in a) { b[substr(i,1,3)]++ }
     for (i in b)
     {
       total+=b[i]
     }
     printf "\nTotal no:of residues - %d\n", total
   }' file.pdb
```

Comment: `grep -B1 TER | awk '{print $6}'` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/TER/{print s; exit} {s=$6}' file
3
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide a more realistic but **minimal** example with concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: for the simplify case it works! thank you! could you tell me would it be possible to save the value as a new variable (assuming that I run in within my bash script in a loop) ? what I can do is just to store it in txt file like awk '/TER/{print s; exit} {s=$6}' file >> file_log.txt

Comment: Basic shell syntax to save the output of a command in a variable: `variable="$(command)"`. Basic shell syntax to save the output of a command in a file: `command > file`. Having said that, it is **extremely** unlikely that calling this in a shell loop is the right way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. Ask a new question if you'd like help with that.

Comment: i have tried like this seq= awk '/TER/{print s; exit} {s=$5}' ./Ev_complex_model_proc.pdb
echo ${seq}
but the result on echo was nothing %) and with the double quites it did not work

Comment: got it thanks again! seq="$(awk '/TER/{print s; exit} {s=$5}' ${file})"

Comment: `seq` is a UNIX command so creating a variable of the same name is a very bad idea.